# How to install CKEditor using NPM on Laravel 8 Jetstream

Tags: laravel, npm, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm lost in a struggle for making CKEditor 5 work in Laravel 8 Jetstream.

I have installed it using npm (I don't want CDN for production mode later on).

### How I installed it

I executed the following `npm` command on the root folder of my Laravel project:

```
npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic --save-dev
```

Then, inside the `app.js` file I added:

```
/** CKEditor 5*/
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor';
window.ClassicEditor = ClassicEditor;
```

Then, inside the view where I require it, looks like the following:

```
{{--Content--}}
<div>
    <x-jet-label value="Content" />
    <textarea wire:model="post.content" rows="6" class="form-control w-full" id="editor"></textarea>
</div>

...

@push('js')
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( 'CKEditor error: '+error );
            } );
    </script>
@endpush
```

I ran npm run dev:

```
npm run dev
```

after that I see the following message:

`webpack compiled successfully`

### It does not work

However, when I visit the page and look at the inspect element (since I see that the CKEditor is not loaded), I get the following log error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined

### What else I've tried

The strange thing is that, if I then call the CDN like so:

```
@push('js')
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( 'CKEditor error: '+error );
            } );
    </script>
@endpush
```

Now I get a different error of calling it twice!:

> Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules

### What works

If I just use the CDN, it does work. However, from the NPM method, it doesn't. If I only leave the NPM, it says it's undefined. If I add the CDN, it says it's duplicated!

The only thing that works is to use the CDN only by removing the

```
/** CKEditor 5*/
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor';
window.ClassicEditor = ClassicEditor;
```

part, from the `app.js` file and `npm run dev` again.

### My question

What am I missing? How do I make it work with the NPM installation?

Comment: Have you tried `import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor';` ?

Comment: Hi, all right, I tried it that way, and still get that `Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined` error. Otherwise, am I missing some setup in the `app.blade.php` layout to pass it to the rest of my views?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in bootsrap.js...

```
window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor');
```

Then run...

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function` instead of `@push`
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts